# File not found error even I didn't mentioned or used the error file name or directory name in code

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle

Am getting an error for file not found for a non existing file name in the code. I haven't used file or directory name in the entire code, still error is thrown.

```
# Extract the features from the images
def extract_features(image_paths):
    features = []
    for image_path in image_paths:
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image = image.resize((224, 224))
        image = np.array(image)
        image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
        image = vgg.predict(image)
        image = np.reshape(image, image.shape[1]*image.shape[2]*image.shape[3])
        features.append(image)
    return np.array(features)

features_train = extract_features(image_paths_train)
features_test = extract_features(image_paths_test)
```

error am getting for the above code is -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_785/4261382143.py in <module>
     12     return np.array(features)
     13 
---> 14 features_train = extract_features(image_paths_train)
     15 features_test = extract_features(image_paths_test)

/tmp/ipykernel_785/4261382143.py in extract_features(image_paths)
      3     features = []
      4     for image_path in image_paths:
----> 5         image = Image.open(image_path)
      6         image = image.resize((224, 224))
      7         image = np.array(image)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3129 
   3130     if filename:
-> 3131         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   3132         exclusive_fp = True
   3133 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 't'
```

pl help

Comment: You should use  some file or directory names as, according to [`Pillow` documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open), `Image.open` expects one as an argument.

Comment: Where `image_paths_train` and `image_paths_test` are coming from and what are their values when you use them?

Comment: @JorgeLuis
  Can you please elaborate

Comment: @DurgaS When you call `Image.open(image_path)` the variable `image_path` should be a path to a file. According to the traceback error it is not a path, but a character `t`. This suggests that `image_paths_train` is not a list of paths, but a plain string.

Comment: What is the value of image_paths passed to extract_features?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy image_paths = '/kaggle/input/'

Comment: So the error is obvious, you are iterating on a string, nowhere you actually find files inside that folder.

Comment: @DurgaS Which is a problem. Each `image_path` must be a path. To do so, you need `image_paths` to be a list of paths. You can try to make a list whose only element is `image_paths`. But that will not work as you need a list of paths to images, not to a folder.

Comment: @DurgaS If you want to get all the files inside your `image_paths` folder, you can use [`Path.iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir)

Comment: @JorgeLuis I used  something like , image_paths = os.listdir('/kaggle/input/sculpture/'), but it's failing to read all image files in the directory even though file is present in it.

Comment: @DurgaS Yes, `os.listdir` is the old fashion equivalent to `Path.iterdir`. That would be a different question and should not be answered here.

Comment: When asking a debugging question, you make it easier on yourself and everyone answering if you include a [MRE] that can be run as-is and demonstrate the problem. If you did so for this, we'd be able to see right away that the `image_paths` variables are set to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier if you debug the issue, as the error is coming on line Image.open(image_path)

Use the following lines to debug:

```
print("Image paths for training set:")
print(image_paths_train)
print("\nImage paths for testing set:")
print(image_paths_test)

features_train = extract_features(image_paths_train)
features_test = extract_features(image_paths_test)
```

If the printed file paths are incorrect or don't exist, you will need to investigate how these variables were created and ensure that they contain the correct file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use assertion for debugging to ensure that your paths are valid. As the others previously stated, there should be something wrong with them, probably a space in a filename, or whatever.

```
from os import path


def extract_features(image_paths):
    features = []
    for image_path in image_paths:
        assert path.exists(image_path), f'Path {image_path} does not exist!'
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image = image.resize((224, 224))
        image = np.array(image)
        image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
        image = vgg.predict(image)
        image = np.reshape(image, image.shape[1]*image.shape[2]*image.shape[3])
        features.append(image)
    return np.array(features)
```